# Scroll bar is there but the page is not scrolling

Tags: html, css

Currently I am working on a website for my girlfriend, and the problem I am having is that I have a scroll bar on the page, but even though the content is overflowing outside of the the page, it is not allowing me to scroll up and down the page. If it helps, I am using the Brackets IDE for this project.

```
 body {

      background-color: rgb(66, 197, 244);
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This is the CSS code I have for my body tag. Is there something I am missing or something I need to add?

Comment: Do you think you could reproduce the issue in a snippet ([mcve]) inside the question itself? (Use the `<>` button in the editor). Ideally it should contain just enough code to reproduce the issue and not more.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate it with what you have posted. What happens when you try to scroll? Also, what does the content of the page look like?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the StackOverflow. No, You're doing fine. Maybe there isn't enough content to scroll.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(66, 197, 244);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you say that you have content overflowing, it is probably missing the overflow property on the html tag too (or some other wrapper that might have dimensions and contain your content). And, as most people already said, if you use a scroll value on the overflow property, it will always show you the scrollbar even if you don't have any content creating overflow. To have a scrollbar only when it is really needed, you should replace "scroll" for "auto".

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `overflow-y: scroll;` it will always show the scroll bar even if there's no content to scroll.

Check this link for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

You just need to add more content to your page or to shrink your window vertical size.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.blue {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
}
.red {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue half">
  <p>No Content</p>
</div>
<div class="red half">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today.

I got the scrollbar to appear on the div as I am accustomed to doing. There was more than enough content in the div to warrant it being scrolled; this was concurred by the scrollbar thumb.

Despite trying many things the scrollbar just refused to scroll. After a ten-minute break, I systematically went through the code, and discovered that the issue was being caused by the z-index of a parent div being -1.

So this solution may assist someone who has this problem caused by one elusive little minx.